# Get file / directory Owner as displayed in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, security, filesystems

When I look at a file or folder in Windows explorer, it generally shows the Owner as a specific user; in my environment, showing as `<domain>\<username>`. It shows this information both when I add the Owner column to a folder view, and by right-clicking on a file and looking at the Details tab. I think this is what most people expect to see when they think about the Owner of a file or directory.

I want to grab this owning-user information for a large number of files and folders. However, when I do what every tutorial, blog post and forum answer suggests to get the Owner programmatically in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), it shows the Owner as `BUILTIN\Administrators`:

```
PS:>Get-Item '.\file.txt' | Get-Acl | Format-List

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::Z:\path\to\file.txt
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : <domain>\Domain Users
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         <domain>\<myusername> Allow  FullControl
Audit  : 
Sddl   : <lots of fancy letters>
```

There are various posts around which explain [why](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=52110) [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc961992(v=technet.10)) [happens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/november/manage-access-to-windows-objects-with-acls-and-the-net-framework#S2) (TL;DR: items created by users who are members of the Administrators group), so don't need to retread that here. And I can see that the info I'm really looking for is there as one of the `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` objects under the `Access` property. I am considering workarounds including [filtering `BUILTIN` / `NT AUTHORITY` records out of the `Access` list](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/2390/get-acl-information-with-powershell/), or perhaps filtering on a class as in [this helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150963/powershell-get-acl-get-members-instead-of-group).

However, those solutions seem both inefficient and inelegant. In the UI, Windows seems to "know what I mean" when I want to see the Owner of an item. So it seems really strange that there's no more straightforward way to grab that information in code.

Where does Explorer pull its Owner information from? Is it really doing some kind of inefficient, heuristic list-filtering under the hood as well?

Or must there not be direct way to approach this?

Solutions in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or any [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) language gratefully received!

---

#### Tried and failed:

The solution [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741786/c-sharp-get-file-owner-in-windows) of calling `.GetAccessControl().GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier))` first, and then `.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount))` on the result, has not worked for me; still outputs only `BUILTIN\Administrators`.

`cmd.exe`'s `dir <file> /Q` gives the same, as suggested in various places including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911134/897137).

Have also found that [`$file.GetAccessControl()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27889169/897137) yields the same, unhelpful info as the `Get-Acl` commandlet.